# How to group a list of symbols or numbers into a # symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

I am trying to create a glossary of terms ordered alphabetically like this example:

```
 -A-
 Alpha
 ATM

 -B-
 Beta
 ...
```

I have no problem to group terms by letter but I wonder how I can manage symbol and digits in order to group them through a # symbol

```
-#-
52 weeks low
@test
```

I figured out to add a column in my Term table where I specify the first letter (in the symbol case I would select a "#" in a select box for example) but I would be pleased to know if there is a better way to achieve this without adding another field.

As info, here is my controller:

```
@terms = Term.all.group_by{|t| t.name[0]}
```

and my view:

```
<% @terms.keys.sort.each do |first_letter| %>
  <%= first_letter %>
  <% @terms[first_letter].each do |term| %>
    <%= term.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this, might be a performance hit, but gets the job done:

```
@terms = Term.all.group_by{|t| t.name[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? t.name[0].capitalize : "#" }
```

Comment: Hi, I user your solution `@locations = Location.all.group_by{|l| l.name[0].capitalize.match(/[A-Z]/) ? l.name[0].capitalize : "#"}`and it works perfect on my local environment but heroku keeps showing me `NoMethodError (undefined method 'capitalize' for 66:Fixnum):`. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to replace `l.name[0]` with `l.name.slice(0,1)`